# inheritance mapping in dozer

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I have Classes hierarchical like this:

```
Class A{
  private int a;
}
Class B extend A{
  private int b;
}
Class C extend A{
  private int c;
}
Class Prime {
  private int a;
  private A objectA;
}
```

And I have DTOs for every single classes like this:

```
Class Dto_A{
  private int a;
}
Class Dto_B extend Dto_A{
  private int b;
}
Class Dto_C extend Dto_A{
  private int c;
}
Class Dto_prime {
  private int prime;
  private Dto_A objectA;
  private int b;
}
```

How can I map field b from `Dto_B` in `Dto_prime` class if `objectA` instance of Dto_B in dozzer? (as below code:)

```
Dto_prime dto_p = new Dto_prime();
Dto_B dto_b = new Dto_B();
if(dto_p.objectA instance of Dto_B)
  dto_p.setB(dto_b.getB());
```

I read [inheritance mapping in dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/baseattributes.html) and add hint in XMLs but it don't work for me and throw exception.

I also try set-method and get-method in XML and do checking like below:

```
if (objectA instance of Dto_B)
   //do something...
```

but when i debug it. `objectA` not instance of none of `Class B` or `Class C`.

**Note**: I persist Prime object with instance of `class B` as field `objectA` in Prime.

Any body have suggestion?